# Updating Wikipedia location data via an api?

Tags: wikipedia

I need to update a number of Wikipedia articles with location info from Geonames via the [coord](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template%3aCoord) template in Wikipedia.  Is there an web services that allows updating of wikipedia location data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt there is such a service. If you want to update Wikipedia pages en masse, you need to follow [Wikipedia's bot policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aBot_policy). The most important part of that is that all bots (programs that make edits automatically) have to be approved.

So, I think what you need to do:

1. Write the bot that edits the articles (possibly using one of the bot libraries).
2. Get approval for the bot.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info.  I'll probably then just edit it manually.